# Pass base64 strings from node.js to a python subprocess through stdin and access the strings on python side

Tags: python, node.js, stdin, child-process, spawn

I am trying to pass data from node.js to a python subprocess called using spawn module, the data are 2 base64 strings.

I think i am already passing the data correctly to python but i dont know how to access them in the python side.

1. How do i access the base64 string as string ?
2. How do i access each string individually ?

**Node.js code:**

```
async mainOcrScript({request}) {

    const front_img = request.front_img_b64
    const back_img = request.back_img_b64
    const debug_mode = request.debug_mode
    const lang = request.lang

    const process =
      await spawn('python3', [Helpers.resourcesPath('pythonScripts/main.py'),
      debug_mode,
      lang
    ]);

    process.stdin.write(front_img); // base64 string
    process.stdin.write(back_img); // base64 string

    process.stdin.end();

    process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    process.on('exit', (code) => {
      console.log("Process quit with code : " + code);
    });
}
```

**Python main.py:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(sys.stdin)

    # How do i access front_img and back_img variables that i had on node.js ? 

    sys.exit()

    main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
```

**When i do:**

```
    print(sys.stdin.read())
```

All i get is a bunch Buffer lines.

Thank you.

Comment: This seems like an overkill solution to me. Can't you just provide the strings via args at the python script startup ? EDIT: sys.exit() kills the script so the following line will never be executed

Comment: @Alexander I tried but i get a error: Error: E2BIG - spawn E2BIG because its too big of a parameter to pass like that i guess, can you help ?